# Getting a NullPointerException when creating a method that adds to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

This is my code:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList;  

public void addGrades(Scanner reader) {
        int grade = reader.nextInt();
        if (grade != -1) {
            this.gradeList.add(grade); // --> NullPointerException
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out why I am getting a `NullPointerException`, because I have made methods like this often without this problem. I thought changing it to this:

```
 public void addGrades(Scanner reader) {
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        while (true) {
            if (grade == -1) {
                break;
            } else {
                this.gradeList.add(grade); // --> NullPointerException
            }
        }
    }
```

would help, but it did not fix the problem. In both cases, the problem is on the line `this.gradeList.add(grade)`. I also tried declaring the ArrayList to be null within the method before the loop, but realized that was redundant. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Has `gradeList` been initialized?

Comment: where do you initiate private ArrayList gradeList;???

Answer (score 5):

You are never instanitating the arraylist. Try

```
private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: This is very likely the reason, but `private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList;` was added to the OP's code by an edit from RKC...

Comment: OK - I'll update my answer to reflect the changes to the OP's question

Comment: I'm an idiot. I initialized the ArrayList in my constructor it fixed it. But I am getting a different error now, an "OutOfMemoryError" that still points to the same line. Is something wrong with my loop or scanner?

Comment: Your `while(true)` loop looks suspicious to me. You are reading the input from the scanner and then adding it _forever_ in to the arraylist

Answer (score 2):

`gradeList` must be `null`. Make sure you initialize it before using it.

It can be initialized like this:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not initializing gradeList.

Either initialize it inline:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Or in a constructor:

```
public MyClass() {
    gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `ArrayList` is initialized.

For instance with an instance field `gradeList` as `ArrayList<Integer>`, use:

```
ArrayList<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

... before referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

*you should must add the ArrayList is initialized. and*

*you should try this following as:*

```
private List<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```